Android - RecyclerView + CollapsingToolbarLayout with Specific Start/End Height Behavior
I'm trying to implement a collapsing toolbar in my Android app with a specific behavior. I want the toolbar to:

Initially start at one-third of the screen height.
Collapse to 15% of the screen height when scrolled up.
Expand to full screen height when scrolled down.

How can I achieve this customized collapsing behavior for the toolbar?

I can answer this in Compose but not using XML is it okay for you?

Sorry we are still using good old XML

My advice is to use MotionLayout to achieve this behaviour.  Here is a lot of examples: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/motionlayout

@Yurii Interesting direction.
